# ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle - date part (century part) shows up wrong

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

using

ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle version 1.0.4637.7382

ServiceStack.OrmLite version 3.9.5

ServiceStack version 3.9.4

The oracle database has a column holding 2 digit year values. When I do a Select using IDbCommand the resulting object list comes with a wrong 4 digit year value. Any data value before 20th century comes back with the "20" prefix and not "19"

Example:
Date in database = 11/21/99

Returns as = 2099/11/21

Supposed to be = 1999/11/21 or 11/21/1999

Hope am clear pointing out the issue, let me know for any additional info

Comment: You want to submit issues like this to the projects issue list: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/issues - be sure to include a failing unit test.

Comment: This is may not be an issue with ormlite.oracle, 'cos the oracle SqlDeveloper shows the date the same way. Guess it is the way oracle renders it.